# NAnt and Vault Documentation

Tags: nant, sourcegear-vault

So I am looking for documentation on the tags  available in NAnt for Vault.  I saw some samples on SourceGear's site but I don't think they are the exhaustive list.  Does anywhere know where I can find documentation on all the eligible tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This documentation along with the NAnt tasks for Vault can be found at [Vault Downloads](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/downloads.html) by downloading "NAnt Tasks (zip)".  The documentation is included in the doc folder in the zip as a CHM.  It contains documentation for all the tasks, with all the attributes for each.

To get the NAnt tasks working copy them to the bin folder in the folder where you have NAnt (where nant.exe is).  Just make sure the Vault tasks match your NAnt release (current latest is for NAnt 0.85).

At some point I also found the source code for this somewhere on SourceGear's websites, but I am not able to do it right now.